# “Analytical” badge wasn't awarded

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

[Analytical](http://www.movies.stackexchange.com/badges/77/analytical) badge is awarded to those who read all the sections of [FAQ](http://www.movies.stackexchange.com/faq). I am pretty sure that I read all the sections of [FAQ](http://www.movies.stackexchange.com/faq), but I did not see analytical badge on my profile.

I also tried using "expand all" option.

In my [english.se](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/16834/vijin-paulraj?tab=activity) profile, i've awarded recently with analytical badge,the same thing i've done in movies.se too.

Comment: I will look into this for you.

Comment: @iandotkelly,But,you've got the analytical badge pretty well!!

Comment: Yes, but I got it a fair while ago - probably in the private beta.  I see that it has been awarded fairly recently to someone though.  I have asked one of the moderators to replicate this, and we will report to SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DFork42 replicated your problem.  I've edited the question to add the [bug] tag.

**Updated:** Vijin.  Someone else managed to get the Analytical badge just now when they offered to replicate your report.  Could you have another go? The advice is to browse *every* link on the page, including the side bar, as well as opening and closing sections.  There are some transitions as you click links - I am also told that you should not rush to click the next link until that transition is complete.

(Bug tag removed)

Comment: Luckily i've got the anlytical badge this time after trying "n no of times"!!!

Comment: Excellent - glad to hear it.